# Creating the equivalent of a SUMIF function in Excel

Tags: r, logical-operators, counting, boolean-logic

I have a set of regressors selected by an optimal variable selection algorithm (out of a total of 30 candidate regressor columns) run on a dataset that looks like the following:

```
> IVs_Selected_by_LASSO
$coefficients
[1] "X4"  "X10" "X19" "X20" "X22" "X25" "X27" "X28"
```

And, I also have the set of actual regressors included in the structural equation describing that dataset, which initially looks like the following:

```
True_IVs
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20
1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
  X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30
1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1


dput(True_IVs)
structure(list(X1 = "0", X2 = "0", X3 = "0", X4 = "1", X5 = "0", 
    X6 = "0", X7 = "0", X8 = "0", X9 = "0", X10 = "1", X11 = "0", 
    X12 = "0", X13 = "1", X14 = "0", X15 = "0", X16 = "0", X17 = "0", 
    X18 = "0", X19 = "1", X20 = "1", X21 = "0", X22 = "1", X23 = "0", 
    X24 = "0", X25 = "1", X26 = "1", X27 = "1", X28 = "1", X29 = "0", 
    X30 = "1"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

However, using the answer to an intermediate question I asked whose answer I was hoping would allow me to finally ask this current question I am asking, I was able to transform the true structural regressors into a format that is able to be logically compared with the format IVs_Selected_by_LASSO is already in as follows:

```
True_Regressors <- names(True_IVs)[True_IVs == 1]
> True_Regressors 
[1] "X4"  "X10" "X13" "X19" "X20" "X22" "X25" "X26" "X27" "X28" "X30"
```

Me being an experienced Excel user, definitely with more experience there than in R, if I had columns or rows with this information in them, I would probably use either a SUMIF or an IF function (with an AUTOSUM at the bottom of the column as you do) to solve this, but I can't figure out how to do the same in R for the life of me.

For example, if I were to do the IF+AUTOSUM solution and pretending that the output of printing True_IVs is in my A column in Excel with IVs_Selected_by_LASSO in the B column, I would use

```
=IF(A1 = B1, 1, 0)
```

And since A1 would be X4 and so would B1, if I put this IF function next to them in the C column, I would get a 1 in cell C1. And after applying the AUTOSUM function at the bottom of column C, I would get 8.

Thus, for this example, I would want to get a function which returns 8 because True_IVs contains all 8 of the variables selected by the LASSO Regression.
Furthermore, for this example, the maximum number possible would be 11 since True_IVs contains 11 variable names, so clearly, IVs_Selected_by_LASSO can only hope to obtain a maximum of 11 matches.

Comment: what is your question? input/expected output?

Comment: Are you looking for `length(names(True_IVs)[True_IVs == 1])`? That would count the number of columns where the value equals 1. Or `sum(as.numeric(True_IVs[True_IVs == 1]))`, which sums the values of the values equal one (both are 11 in your example). But unsure if this is your question since your title says SUMIF and your body text says COUNT.

Comment: The `sum` of a logical vector will give you the count of TRUE's in a logical vector. Do you want to use your intermediate result, `True_Regressors` with `length`? Or do you want: `sum( True_Regressors %in% IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients)` which returns 
`[1] 8`

Comment: @rawr thank you for the clarifying question, I just added that all important information in at the bottom!

Comment: `sum(True_IVs == 1)`? There are 11 columns with 1s in them, so I'm not clear why you want 7 as the output.

Comment: @JonSpring Because I am trying to measure how many of the variables the LASSO Regression I ran selected were correct, the maximum amount that I could get back would be 11 for a True Positive Rate aka Sensitivity of 100%. I already know that all 11 of the variables in the True_IVs object are correct, hence the name lol

Comment: @jpsmith ooo, my bad, excellent catch of my typo where I accidentally put COUNT in the body of the question, I just fixed that, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: I am counting 8 values in `IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients` that are also columns where `True_IVs == 1` - in other words, all 8 names in `IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients` are also in `True_IVs` and have a values of 1 - could you articulate where 7 comes from exactly?

Comment: @jpsmith I just now finally noticed that a minute ago after reading IRTFM's comment and have fixed that typo, if I had the function I asked the question to try to obtain, I wouldn't have made this mistake lol, but I didn't so I counted by just looking at the output for a second.

Comment: I'm still unclear on how you get 7 and not 8, based on the statement "which returns 7 because True_IVs contains all 8 of the variables selected by the LASSO Regression"

Comment: @jpsmith I am just an idiot and thought I had fully corrected the typo in question by my most recent reply to you but just discovered, to my utter horror, that I had not yet. Hopefully, all mentions of 7 being the correct output have been removed now finally.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck your proposed solution works for me when I ran it on this example, so I am almost ready to accept it if you want to re-enter it as an answer, but first I have to ask, will it still work if for whatever reason, the output returned by either column are in the wrong order? They shouldn't ever be anyway, but better safe than sorry, ya know

Comment: @Spencer - you aren't an idiot, just a totally reasonable mistake :) Thanks for clarifying and making sure I wasn't going crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options as mentioned by others and myself in the comments, but the issue here seems to be a disconnect between Excel logic and R logic, so I will try to provide more detailed insight as a formal answer.

As you know, your excel code:

```
=IF(A1 = B1, 1, 0)
```

Will check the single cell in `A1` to see if it is equal to the single cell `B1`, and that can be copied down the line.

If take the vector of column names of your data frame `True_IVs` (which has 30 columns) via `names(True_IVs)` and think of it as all 30 column names a being copied and pasted into a column in excel, we can check those names against another vector of names - here `IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients`. *Except* instead of one-cell-vs-one-cell we can check if the name appears in the whole vector by using `%in%`:

```
names(True_IVs) %in% IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients
```

Which checks if each value in `names(True_IVs)` is in *any* of the  values in `IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients`. So, for instance, if the fist value in `names(True_IVs)` is anywhere in `IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients`, it will return `TRUE`, else it will return `FALSE`. Running this across the whole vector returns a boolean vector of length 30:

```
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [25]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

The values of which corresponds to if each element in the `names(True_IVs)` is found anywhere in the `IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients` vector.

Secondly, as noted in the comments, when summing R assumes `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 0`, so wrapping this in a `sum` will return the total number included:

```
sum(names(True_IVs) %in% IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients)
# [1] 8
```

This provides more flexibility, particularly if the values are out of order. For instance, if we scramble the values to a random order:

```
IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients <- sample(IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients, length(IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients))
```

We get the same result:

```
sum(names(True_IVs) %in% IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients)
# [1] 8
```

---

There are of course multiple other ways to do this, for instance @G. Grothendieck mentions elegantly using `length` and `intersect`:

```
length(intersect(IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients, names(True_IVs))) # Thanks G. Grothendieck
# [1] 8
```

Or more inelegantly using `length` with `names(True_IVs)` instead of `sum`:

```
length(names(True_IVs)[names(True_IVs) %in% IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients])
# [1] 8
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And I'll ask you the same question I just asked the other gentleman who provided me with a working solution a few minutes ago in the comment section, will this also work if for whatever reason, either the Variables in IVs_Selected_by_LASSO or those in True_IVs are out of order? I assume so with your answer specifically because the functions name in sounds more flexible than a logical equals operator to me as someone who is also verses in SQL, not just Excel.

Comment: FANTASTIC, thank you so much kind sir, this will help me out quite a bit in this project. I have finally begin to learn how to limit the length of my questions and ask one clearer question at a time, so I may come back with a new question about how to apply this function iteratively using an apply or a map function to a set of LASSO selections and corresponding Structural Equations, but this is all I needed for now :)

Comment: Well, I have tried my best to figure out how to expand this logic in order to apply to the multiple datasets stored in a single object case as I alluded to in my last comment, but I just can't get it to work. 
Oddly, that main problem boils down to the column names, for some reason, when I import a file-folder's worth of data sets into an object rather than 1, it doesn't keep the new column names when I re-assign them, so all of the columns are auto-named V1, V2, V3, etc. so now neither your nor the other guy's solutions work anymore :(

Comment: should I just ask a whole new question or try to add the new issues in at the bottom of this question??

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to compute the number of elements in common to both `IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients` and `True_Regressors` then

```
length(intersect(IVs_Selected_by_LASSO$coefficients, True_Regressors))
```

`intersect` does not require that the contents of the arguments be in the same order.

Note that there is an R package called [ExcelFunctionsR](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ExcelFunctionsR) and also if you google *R SUMIF* you will get some hits.