# Creating the R version of an Excel SUMIF function which can be used to measure the performance of a model run on many datasets consecutively

Tags: r, performance-testing, data-manipulation, transformation, data-preprocessing

First, this question is a follow up on a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74956321/creating-the-equivalent-of-a-sumif-function-in-excel/74958483#74958483) of mine on Stack Overflow which was answer satisfactorily, but in a more complicated domain/application.

However, this time, I am replicating the same calculation/operation on both the selections made on a number of datasets and the corresponding true models for those datasets which means the same functions cannot apply directly.

And, a much bigger problem is that when loading a file-folder of datasets into an object in R rather than loading one dataset into an object, it automatically names the 31 columns V1:31 and I cannot renamed the columns for each dataset easily after they are loaded.

So, instead of having

```
df<- read.csv("0-11-3-462.csv", header = FALSE)
# change column names of all the columns in the dataframe 'df'
colnames(df) <- c("Y", "X1","X2", "X3", "X4","X5", "X6", "X7","X8", "X9",
                  "X10","X11", "X12", "X13","X14", "X15", "X16","X17", 
                  "X18", "X19","X20", "X21", "X22","X23", "X24", "X25",
                  "X26", "X27", "X28","X29", "X30")
True_IVs <- df[1, -1]
```

With the outcome being:

```
> str(True_IVs)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ X1 : chr "0"
 $ X2 : chr "0"
 $ X3 : chr "0"
 $ X4 : chr "1"
 $ X5 : chr "0"
 $ X6 : chr "0"
 $ X7 : chr "0"
 $ X8 : chr "0"
```

...

I now have:

```
filepaths_list <- list.files(path = filepath, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
datasets <- lapply(filepaths_list, read.csv, header = FALSE)

True_IVs <- lapply(datasets, function(j) {j[1, -1]})

datasets <- lapply(datasets, function(i) {i[-1:-3, ]})
datasets <- lapply(datasets, \(X) { lapply(X, as.numeric) })
```

Where datasets looks like this (where V actually goes all the way up to V31, and this is just the head of the 1st dataset in the datasets object of course):

```
> head(datasets[[1]], n = 5)
                 V1           V2          V3          V4           V5
1 Regressor present            0           0           0            1
2                              1           2           3            4
3                 Y           X1          X2          X3           X4
4       4.119024459 -1.350655759 1.901787258 0.205749783  0.242920532
5       1.737430635   0.26677565 0.054290757 1.510124319 -0.618655652
            V6           V7          V8           V9         V10
1            0            0           0            0           0
2            5            6           7            8           9
3           X5           X6          X7           X8          X9
4 -0.405946237 -0.667673545 0.745735562  0.143317951 1.376182976
5  0.289294477 -0.220927214 0.251479422 -0.094245944 0.792214818
```

And skipping forward to the same part where the previous question began, now in the higher dimensional case, for IVs_Selected_by_BE, it comes out as:

```
> IVs_Selected_by_BE
[[1]]
 [1] "V3"  "V4"  "V5"  "V6"  "V9"  "V11" "V14" "V16" "V18" "V20" "V21"
[12] "V23" "V26" "V27" "V28" "V29" "V31"

[[2]]
 [1] "V3"  "V6"  "V7"  "V8"  "V9"  "V12" "V13" "V14" "V15" "V17" "V18"
[12] "V21" "V22" "V23" "V24" "V25" "V26" "V30"
```

Which is annoying and disconcerting, but then the same happens (more or less) with

```
True_Regressors now as well:
[[1]]
 [1] "V5"  "V11" "V14" "V20" "V21" "V23" "V26" "V27" "V28" "V29" "V31"

[[2]]
 [1] "V7"  "V8"  "V14" "V15" "V17" "V18" "V21" "V22" "V24" "V26" "V30"
```

Note: True_Regressors was obtained by running:

```
True_Regressors <- lapply(True_IVs, function(i) { names(i)[i == 1] })
# verus only having to use this for the single dataset case previously
True_Regressors <- names(True_IVs)[True_IVs == 1]
```

My problem here is that the numbers attached to the right of each V are wrong, all of them are exactly 1 too large.

Answer (score 2):

with package [vroom](https://vroom.r-lib.org/index.html) that's straightforward:

- read in all `.csv` files in your `getwd()` into a dataframe in one go, store file source in column "source_file":

```
library(dplyr)
library(vroom)
all_data <- vroom(list.files(pattern = 'csv'), id = 'source_file')
```

(actually you don't read them in, but create a lookup index, which is executed when needed ... which makes vroom so fast)

- rename columns (except "source_file"):

```
names(all_data)[-1] <- paste0('X', 1:(ncol(all_data)-1))
```

- add row number (per source file) as second column:

```
all_data <- all_data |>
    group_by(source_file) |>
    mutate(row_number = row_number(), .before = 2)
```

output so far:

```
> all_data |> head(3)
# A tibble: 3 x 38
# Groups:   source_file [1]
  source_f~1 row_n~2    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10
  <chr>        <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 file1.csv        1   418   676   712   243   319    82   699   851   501   207
2 file1.csv        2   688   402   762   964   895   513   424   335   993   119
3 file1.csv        3   135   201    37    13   104   378   661   874   586   302
# ... with 26 more variables: X11 <dbl>, X12 <dbl>, X13 <dbl>, X14 <dbl>,
#   X15 <dbl>, X16 <dbl>, X17 <dbl>, X18 <dbl>, X19 <dbl>, X20 <dbl>,
#   X21 <dbl>, X22 <dbl>, X23 <dbl>, X24 <dbl>, X25 <dbl>, X26 <dbl>,
#   X27 <dbl>, X28 <dbl>, X29 <dbl>, X30 <dbl>, X31 <dbl>, X32 <dbl>,
#   X33 <dbl>, X34 <dbl>, X35 <dbl>, X36 <dbl>, and abbreviated variable names
#   1: source_file, 2: row_number
# i Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

- `filter`/ `select` / `mutate` ... as needed:

```
True_IVs <- all_data |>
    filter(row_number == 1) |>
    select(X1)

datasets <- all_data |> filter(row_number > 3)
```

**Edit**
If, as indicated, you need to skip leading rows, you can do so by setting the `skip` argument: e. g. `vroom(..., skip = 2)` to skip lines 1-2.

If you need all leading rows but reorder them later, you can set the column names like:

```
all_data <- vroom(list.files(pattern = 'csv'), 
                  id = 'source_file',
                  col_names = paste('X', 1:n) ## n = column count in source files
                  )
```

and filter / reorder according to row number as described earlier.

Comment: I_O your solution looks very promising to me, unfortunately, there is a fatal flaw in the way the datasets my research collaborator generated for us I hadn't appreciated until just now which is that he made the first row the row of binary indicators which specify which true variables describe each dataset when he should have made that the 2nd row.

Because of this, when I ran the first line in your proposed answer, I got:
Error: Files must have consistent column names:                                                               
* File 1 column 5 is: 1
* File 2 column 5 is: 0

Comment: is this something that is fixable without having to regenerate the synthetic datasets with the first two rows switched?? Because it already took my collaborator almost a week to generate all 260,000 of the csv files we are using here. So it would be most unfortunate if he had to do it again!

Comment: Do you have to keep the first line? If not, `vroom(..., skip = 1)` should do the trick.

Comment: the first line of which object exactly? Sorry, I guess I need clear pointers too.

Comment: first line of each csv-file

Comment: the first line of each csv file is the only one that matters for this part actually, those 1s and 0s indicate which are the variables actually in the so-called structural equation characterizing each dataset.

Comment: Actually, somehow, me typing that last comment made me realize that there is an alternative possible way to equalize for formats of the output stored in True_Regressors and IVs_Selected_by_BE! Just convert the format in the opposite direction by removing the Xs in front of the variable number in every element stored in IVs_Selected_by_BE instead. Would that be any easier??