# Error: Files must have consistent column names: * File 1 column 5 is: 1 * File 2 column 5 is: 0

Tags: r, machine-learning, transformation, feature-selection, reproducible-research

Note: all of the datasets and scripts referenced here can be easily found in my
[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/EER-Research-Project) for this research project. The code referenced and reprinted both in this question and the one linked to in the previous question should be in the script called "Both BE & FS script(40) - prepped for Antony" (Dr. Antony Davies is the principle researcher on this project).

This question is technically a follow up on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74964181/creating-the-r-version-of-an-excel-sumif-function-which-can-be-used-to-measure-t), which itself was a follow up of a question before that. I firmly believe that the proposed answer in the previous question which can be found in the link would work in most cases, but my datasets have an unusual characteristic, they have no headers, and their top rows are not the variable names, the 3rd rows contain the variable names. Instead, their top rows contain which variables were selected by a variable selection algorithm (LASSO, Backward Stepwise, or Forward Stepwise) denoted as binary indicators, basically dummy variables as can be seen in the screenshot below:
[image]

This peculiar feature of these datasets I am loading into R and storing in a list/dataframe object I call 'datasets' means that when I ran the proposed solution to the previous question, I got this back in the Console:

```
all_data <- vroom(list.files(pattern = 'csv'), id = 'source_file')
Error: Files must have consistent column names: * File 1 column 5 is: 1 * File 2 column 5 is: 0
```

I can clearly see what the problem is here, but I don't know how to fix it without asking my collaborator on this research project to edit part of the custom Excel Macro he wrote which he used to generate the 260,000 synthetic datasets we are running his new algorithm and the several Benchmark Algorithms on and then have him run it again on his second computer for half a week or more just so I can avoid this error at this very last step in measuring the performance of the Benchmark Methods!

p.s. 1 - Just to make myself clearer here, the best format I could have after transforming their current state would be for the top row to be what the 2nd row currently is, except with Xs in front of ever number, or equivalently, what is in the 3rd row starting with column #2, and what is currently in the 1st row right below that proper 1st row or header. I already know exactly how to write functions to score the selections if I can get the output in that format!

p.s. 2 - Again, the way that I got here in case it is too much trouble for you to quickly toggle between two tabs or between two tabs and an Rscript, I use the following code to get to where my issue is:

```
setwd("/datasets folder's location on my laptop")
filepaths_list <- list.files(path = filepath, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
# reformat the names of each of the csv file formatted datasets
DS_names_list <- basename(filepaths_list)
DS_names_list <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(DS_names_list)

datasets <- lapply(filepaths_list, read.csv, header = FALSE)

True_IVs <- lapply(datasets, function(j) {j[1, -1]})

datasets <- lapply(datasets, function(i) {i[-1:-3, ]})
datasets <- lapply(datasets, \(X) { lapply(X, as.numeric) })
datasets <- lapply(datasets, function(i) { as.data.frame(i) })
# the line below won't run without the line above it having been run 1st
datasets <- lapply(datasets, \(X) { round(X, 3) })  

# fit all of the Backward Stepwise Regressions
set.seed(11)      # for reproducibility
system.time(BE.fits <- parLapply(CL, datasets, \(X) {
    full_models <- lm(X$V1 ~ ., X)
    back <- step(full_models, scope = formula(full_models), 
                    direction = 'back', trace = FALSE) }) )
# extract their fitted coefficients
BE_Coeffs <- lapply(seq_along(BE.fits), function(i) coef(BE.fits[[i]]))

# extract just the candidate variables they select by name
# this is one of the two components needed for performance measurment
IVs_Selected_by_BE <- lapply(seq_along(BE.fits), 
                             \(i) names(coef(BE.fits[[i]])[-1]))

# this is the other component needed for performance measurement
True_Regressors <- lapply(True_IVs, function(i){names(i)[i == 1]})
```

Comment: It's considered poor form to reference (potentially large) files elsewhere.  Please post a **small, reproducible** example of maybe two source files with column names that trigger your error.

Comment: BTW,  you should string your "collaborator" up by his toes for using Excel (ugh) Macros (triple ugh) to preprocess data.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft sorry for my miscommunication if that's what you got from what I said, he did not preprocess the data using Excel, he created the data using Excel. Very different!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Oh oh ohhhh, so sorry, my mistake, the way I have failed to explain certain minor details regarding my question makes it appear that my sample code is from my Script run on the full set of 260k datasets. This is not the case, if you look in the 1st paragraph where I specify all the code comes from my script called ""Both BE & FS script(40)..." that (40) indicates that this version runs on a smaller folder with a subset of just 40 datasets called 'last 40'.
As you might imagine, the full data folder is not in my Repository, but 'last 40' is!

Comment: One more thing I would be remiss to omit here, this research project revolves around exploring the statistical properties of a new variable selection algorithm which my collaborator has proposed, he is the principle author. This is all based on a 2008 Working Paper he wrote by himself, I am just helping him update the Benchmark Methods and to write & submit an improved 2nd draft for publication!