# Correcting the output of a custom function which measures the True Positive Rate of a variable selection algorithm

Tags: r, performance, regression, feature-selection

**NOTE:** This question is the 3rd and final question on here all trying to solve the same complicated problem, but asked in steps. The previous question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74964181/creating-the-r-version-of-an-excel-sumif-function-which-can-be-used-to-measure-t) and the initial question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74956321/creating-the-equivalent-of-a-sumif-function-in-excel). Furthermore, the code used in this question all comes from the "LASSO_code(10)" Rscript, which only uses data found in the folder called "ten" up on my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/EER-Research-Project) for this Statistical Learning research project.

The main improvement I have right off the bat in the current state of my code over where I left off at the end of the previous question is that now, after loading the list of dataframes into the workspace and assigning them to datasets using:

```
datasets <- lapply(filepaths_list, read.csv)
```

I also figured out (finally!) how to correct the column names for each of the dataframes in that list by executing:

```
# change column names of all the columns in the dataframe 'datasets'
datasets <- lapply(datasets, function(dataset_i) { 
  colnames(dataset_i) <- c("Y", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", 
                           "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", "X12", "X13", "X14", 
                           "X15", "X16", "X17", "X18", "X19", "X20", "X21", 
                           "X22", "X23", "X24", "X25", "X26", "X27", "X28", 
                           "X29", "X30")
  dataset_i })
```

Beyond that, in order to re-create the multiple dataset/dataframe version of the 'True_IVs' object I created back during the [original version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74956321/creating-the-equivalent-of-a-sumif-function-in-excel), I have also added in the following two commands:

```
Structural_IVs_chr <- lapply(datasets, function(j) {j[1, -1]})    
> Structural_IVs_chr[[1]]
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
  X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Structural_IVs_num <- lapply(Structural_IVs_chr, \(X) { lapply(X, as.numeric) })
```

Plus, I have also gotten around the need to create the True_IVs object used in the most recent version of my code I asked about in the last post by utilizing my new Structural_IVs_chr object in the following manner:

```
True_Regressors <- lapply(Structural_IVs_chr, function(i) {
  names(i)[i == 1] })
> head(True_Regressors, n = 3)
[[1]]
[1] "X11" "X13" "X16"    
[[2]]
[1] "X6"  "X7"  "X20"
[[3]]
[1] "X9"  "X10" "X20"
```

And once again, the same is in the previous posts, I am writing a function which counts how many elements in the prior output equal elements in the selected variables chosen by a LASSO Regression on those datasets stored in the following format:

```
> head(IVs_Selected_by_LASSO, n = 3)
[[1]]
[1] "X11" "X16"    
[[2]]
[1] "X6"  "X7"  "X20"    
[[3]]
[1] "X9"  "X10" "X20"
```

And finally, here are my attempts to write the performance measuring function I am asking help for here:

```
### Count up how many Variables Selected match  the true 
### structural equation variables for that dataset in order
### to measure LASSO's performance.
Total_Positives <- lapply(True_Regressors, function(i) { length(i) })
> head(Total_Positives, n = 3)
[[1]]
[1] 3    
[[2]]
[1] 3    
[[3]]
[1] 3

True_Pos_list1 <- lapply(seq_along(datasets), \(i)
                        length(intersect(IVs_Selected_by_LASSO, 
                                         True_Regressors)) )
> head(True_Pos_list1, n = 3)
[[1]]
[1] 9
[[2]]
[1] 9
[[3]]
[1] 9

True_Pos_list2 <- lapply(seq_along(datasets), \(i)
                         sum(IVs_Selected_by_LASSO %in% True_Regressors))
> head(True_Pos_list2, n = 3)
[[1]]
[1] 9
[[2]]
[1] 9
[[3]]
[1] 9
```

As ought to be clear, the results should be:

```
> head(True_Pos_list, n = 3)
    [[1]]
    [1] 2
    [[2]]
    [1] 3
    [[3]]
    [1] 3
```

And furthermore, the result returned for any element in the True_Pos_list should never be larger than the corresponding element in the Total_Positives list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running:

```
True_Pos_list <- lapply(seq_along(datasets), \(i)
                                    sum(IVs_Selected_by_LASSO[[i]] %in% 
                                          True_Regressors[[i]]))
```

instead, see how that works. I am not sure why you erroneously got 9 back for the number of True Positives, but this should fix the output, and that seems to be your most urgent concern here.